# What is the most efficient way to call another function in parent function to execute Palindrome function?

Tags: palindrome

In programming, there are multiple ways of doing the same problem.  The following problem is in regards to palindrome.  Though I feel that I am on the right track, I am not able to completely solve the problem to get to requested solution.

What is a palindrome?  A word written forward or backward is the same and returns true.  Example, "racecar".  Hence, I designed the following code in Javascript...

```
function palindrome(string) {
string = string.toLowerCase();
lowString = string.toLowerCase().split("").reverse().join("");
 for (var i=0; i<string.length; i++) {
 if (string[i] !== lowString[i]) {
 return false;
 }
}
}
return true;
}
```

The above code returns true if Palindrome exists and returns false if not.

Then, the problem says - Given various palindrome in a string or array, please return the longest palindrome.  So, I wrote the following:

```
function longestPalindrome(newstring) {
 splitString = newString.split(" ");
 for (var i=0; i < splitString; i++) {
 if (splitString[i] == palindrome(splitString[i]) {
   console.log(splitString[i]);
  }
  }
  }
  longestPalindrome("This is a racecar ada");'
```

But in the above code, I am not able to get the required outcome because I believe I am not calling the function correctly.

I would appreciate clear directions or even a solution built off of my track as well as the track you deem fittest.